# JNLP FileSaveService ignoring the name and extension given while invoking the saveAsFileDialog method

Tags: java, file-io, jnlp, java-web-start, savefiledialog

I have a requirement of passing command line parameters when mounting .dmg on MAC for this I have used JNLP which is dynamically composed using JSP with response content-type as `application/x-java-jnlp-file`. The content of JSP is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://10.40.42.134:8080/TestJNLP/">
 <information>
    <title>jnlp.JSP</title>
    <vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</vendor>
 </information>
 <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="lib/faren2.jar" main="true" />
 </resources>
 <application-desc name="Dynamic Tree Demo Application" main-class="org.Test" width="300" height="300">
    <argument><%=request.getParameter("arg1")%></argument>  
    <argument><%=request.getParameter("arg2")%></argument> 
 </application-desc>
 <security>
    <all-permissions/>
 </security>
</jnlp>
```

JNLP is correctly invoked with the parameters I pass.

Now there are **two** problems moving further:

**First**, After triggering JNLP my main-class invokes `saveFileDialog` from `FileSaveService` for saving the .dmg on user system but JNLP Client (Save Dialog which open on MAC) is ignoring the name and extensions which I am passing while invoking the method.
How can we make the JNLP Client to honor the name and extension I am passing?

**Second**, How can I know the path where user has saved the .dmg so that I can mount it programatically? This is very critical knowing the path where user has saved the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is possible with `FileSaveService`.

The path and extension arguments to `saveFileDialog` are only hints.  The implementation is free to ignore them.

`FileContents.getName()` will tell you only the name, not the directory.  This is by design.  JNLP apps that depend on `FileSaveService` are considered untrusted, and paths are potentially a privacy issue.  If I choose to save the DMG file in a directory called `C:\Users\S_Rushdie\My Documents\Porn` I may not want your program to include that in a log that is later uploaded to your server.

If you need greater control, I think you will need to sign your app, grant it `<all-permission/>` and use a `JFileChooser` and `FileOutputStream` instead.

Comment: Spot on.  +1, especially for the directory name.  Says it all.  ;)

Comment: Thanks @finnw. I am using JFileChooser Now.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Just a general query for you, why do we need FileSaveService then if we already have JFileChooser. I guess you are the best person to answer this

Comment: @Harshdeep For situations where the app. does not need to know the location that a resource is opened from, or saved to.  Situations like this little [animated GIF maker](http://pscode.org/gifanim/).  GIFanim comes both free-floating and embedded.  It can load frames and save the resulting animated GIF, and is entirely sand-boxed.  :)